# Group Item in Kendo UI Combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, kendo-ui

I want to grouping item in Kendo UI combobox.

My datasoure is -

```
$("#ddlTest_I").kendoComboBox({
        dataTextField: "parentName",
        dataValueField: "parentId",
        dataSource: [
                { parentName: "Parent1", parentId: 1, childName: "Child1", childId: 1 },
                { parentName: "Parent2", parentId: 2, childName: "Child2", childId: 2 },
                { parentName: "Parent1", parentId: 1, childName: "Child3", childId: 3 },
                { parentName: "Parent2", parentId: 2, childName: "Child4", childId: 4 },
                { parentName: "Parent1", parentId: 1, childName: "Child5", childId: 5 }
            ]
    });
```

I try data bind to Kendo UI combobox -

```
$("#ddlTest_II").kendoComboBox({
        cascadeFrom: "ddlTest_I",
        dataTextField: "childName",
        dataValueField: "childId",
        dataSource: [            
                {parentName: "Parent1", parentId: 1, childName: "Child1", childId: 1 },
                { parentName: "Parent2", parentId: 2, childName: "Child2", childId: 2 },
                { parentName: "Parent1", parentId: 1, childName: "Child3", childId: 3 },
                { parentName: "Parent2", parentId: 2, childName: "Child4", childId: 4 },
                { parentName: "Parent1", parentId: 1, childName: "Child5", childId: 5 }
            ]
    });
```

I want to use KendoUI combobox cascadeFrom format.But items are duplicate at parent.

This is sample.I don't want twice to pull data from DB. I collected all data in one source to use.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You will not have to call DB twice, but you will need two datasources.

1. Parent dataset reads
2. On the parent datasource read complete, take data from parent dataset and copy them into new dataset and use [grouping configuration](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-group) to group the data in this new dataset. To do the copying use [datasource for local data](http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/use-the-datasource-component#creating-a-datasource-for-local-data)

   ```
   var comboDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(parentDatasource.data()); // pseudo
   comboDataSource.add(parentDatasource.data()[0]); // might need add item by item
   ```
3. Combo feeds of the new dataset